# Playing background music across storyboard.

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having trouble when playing background music in my app.

First, I start the music at ViewDidLoad method in the first storyboard view controller. It continues to play even when i jump from page to page, which is fine using the following code

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                         pathForResource:@"background"
                                         ofType:@"mp3"]];
```

My problem is, for example if i want to change music at the 10th page. How can I stop the music i previously played at the 10th page file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exact setup is unclear. I'd suggest you setting up your music inside a singleton object, and sharing the AVAudioPlayer between all views instead. But if you would like to set them up from view to view, you might consider stopping it when the view is going to disappear.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated;
```

or perhaps

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender;
```

Comment: Hi, I still can't get it right. Do you have any tutorial for the singleton or example? Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way would be to have a singleton 'player controller' that can be accessed across any view controller. Have a generic play, pause, stop function. You could init with a specific url that could be changed at runtime (by keeping the url as a property of the 'player controller' class).